# how dismissModalViewcontroller works,iphone

Tags: iphone

Supposed I have ViewA and ViewB and I am using modal view controller such as

```
[ViewA presentModalViewController:ViewB animated:YES]
```

Then in order to dismiss the ViewB,

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

is invoked

**Question** :

what does **self** mean here.Is it ViewB or ViewA.

where should we put that code in? Should it be in ViewA or ViewB.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself, however, it automatically forwards the message to
>   the presenting view controller."

So, `self` is whatever object contains the code you quoted but, either way, the message ends up being processed by ViewA.

(Note that the documentation **also** says this is a deprecated method.)

Answer (score 0):

ViewB should be dismissed. It should be in ViewB's view controller as that is the modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

from apple doc "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, however, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller."

it's clear

Answer (score 0):

dismissModalViewController should be placed into the modal view controller you want to dismiss. It is in charge of dismissing itself.

That said, you should no longer be using the modal functions. You should be using presentViewController and dismissViewController. The modal functions are deprecated and may be removed soon.